# How to move one class character to another class in c++

Tags: c++

My code outputs weird numbers. in line "return this->x + this->y + this->z; " it should output all this 3 number sum, but it outputs weird numbers. Expected result:  11

Anyone can help with this?

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class Point2D {

protected:
    double x,y;

public:

    Point2D() {
        std::cout << "Objekts izveidots bez parametriem." << std::endl;
    }

    void setx(double x) {
        this->x = x;
    }

    void sety(double y) {
        this->y = y;
    }

    double getsumma() {
        return this->x + this->y;
    }

    void printInfo() {
        std::cout << "Divu malu summa ir:" << getsumma() << std::endl;
    }

    ~Point2D() {
        std::cout << "Izdzests" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Point3D : public Point2D {
protected:
    double z;

public:

    Point3D() {
        std::cout << "Objekts izveidots bez parametriem." << std::endl;
    }

    void setz(double z) {
        this->z = z;
    }


    double getperimetrs() {
        return this->x + this->y + this->z;
    }

    void printInfo() {
        std::cout << "Trijstura perimentrs ir: " << getperimetrs() << std::endl;
    }

    ~Point3D() {
        std::cout << "Izdzests" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {

    Point2D z1;
    Point3D x1;

    z1.setx(5);
    z1.sety(3);
    x1.setz(5);

    z1.printInfo();
    x1.printInfo();

    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by moving character from one class to another?

Comment: Apart from the unclear question, it's bad practice to have public inheritance between two concrete classes.

Comment: @BoR Why's that?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724946/why-derive-from-a-concrete-class-is-a-poor-design

Comment: @BoR Meh, just sounds like a good excuse to force everybody onto poorly-performing and hard to read polymorphic inheritance hierarchies. For nice simple types like this there's really just no need at all.

Comment: Change your constructor to `Point2D() : x{0.0/0.0}, y{0.0/0.0} { std::cout << "Objekts izveidots bez parametriem." << std::endl; }`.

Answer (score 3):

In `x1` you are only setting the Z value. X and Y are in an uninitialized state. Thus you don't know their values are when you add them.

Otherwise, you might be interested in this program:

```
#include <iostream>

class Point2D {
protected:
    double x, y;
public:
    Point2D(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) {
        std::cout << "Objekts izveidots bez parametriem.\n";
    }

    double getsumma() const {
        return x + y;
    }

    virtual void printInfo() const {
        std::cout << "Divu malu summa ir: " << getsumma() << '\n';
    }

    virtual ~Point2D() {
        std::cout << "Izdzests\n";
    }
};

class Point3D : public Point2D {
protected:
    double z;

public:
    Point3D(double x, double y, double z) : Point2D(x, y), z(z) {
        std::cout << "Objekts izveidots bez parametriem.\n";
    }

    double getperimetrs() const {
        return getsumma() + z;
    }

    void printInfo() const override {
        std::cout << "Trijstura perimentrs ir: " << getperimetrs() << '\n';
    }

    ~Point3D() override {
        std::cout << "Izdzests\n";
    }

};

int main() {

    Point2D z1(5, 3);
    Point3D x1(5, 3, 5);

    z1.printInfo();
    x1.printInfo();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not how inheritance works.

You have two different, distinct, unrelated, separate objects:

- One is a `Point2D` called `z1`, whose members `x` and `y` you set.
- The other is a `Point3D` called `x1`, whose member `z` you set.

Just because the type `Point3D` inherits from `Point2D` doesn't mean that there is any relationship between these two particular instances.

`z1`'s `z` is not set, and `x1`'s `x` and `y` are not set. Those members are left uninitialised, with unspecified values, hence your dodgy output.

I think you probably just meant to make *one* object, like this:

```
Point3D obj;
obj.setx(5);
obj.sety(3);
obj.setz(5);
obj.printInfo();
```

*[The output is 13](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d7c68d5784599a6) (5+3+5 is not 11).*

Inheritance is how you can do `setx` and `sety` on a `Point3D`, because those functions are *inherited* from its `Point2D` base.

Another way of looking at it is that every `Point3D` has a "hidden" `Point2D` inside it automatically (by inheritance). You don't need to make one yourself.