# Is -Wreturn-std-move clang warning correct in case of objects in the same hierarchy?

Tags: c++, clang, warnings, c++17, move

Consider the following simple code:

```
struct Base
{
  Base() = default;      
  Base(const Base&);      
  Base(Base&&);
};

struct Derived : Base { };

Base foo()
{
  Derived derived;
  return derived;
}
```

*clang 8.0.0* [gives a warning `-Wreturn-std-move`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/B7F0Tl1CG4rW300n) on it:

> ```
> prog.cc:21:10: warning: local variable 'derived' will be copied despite being returned by name [-Wreturn-std-move]
>   return derived;
>          ^~~~~~~
> prog.cc:21:10: note: call 'std::move' explicitly to avoid copying
>   return derived;
>          ^~~~~~~
>          std::move(derived)
> ```

But if one called `std::move` here the behavior of the code might change because the `Base` subobject of the `Derived` object would be moved before the calling of the destructor of the `Derived` object and the code of the last would behave differently.

E.g. look at [the code (compiled with the `-Wno-return-std-move` flag)](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KwNFMUPVkcQ6SHEm):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

struct Base
{
  bool flag{false};

  Base()
  {
    std::cout << "Base construction" << std::endl;
  }

  Base(const bool flag) : flag{flag}
  {
  }

  Base(const Base&)
  {
    std::cout << "Base copy" << std::endl;
  }

  Base(Base&& otherBase)
  : flag{otherBase.flag}
  {
    std::cout << "Base move" << std::endl;
    otherBase.flag = false;
  }

  ~Base()
  {
    std::cout << "Base destruction" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
  Derived()
  {
    std::cout << "Derived construction" << std::endl;
  }

  Derived(const bool flag) : Base{flag}
  {
  }

  Derived(const Derived&):Base()
  {
    std::cout << "Derived copy" << std::endl;
  }

  Derived(Derived&&)
  {
    std::cout << "Derived move" << std::endl;
  }

  ~Derived()
  {
    std::cout << "Derived destruction" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Flag: " << flag << std::endl;
  }
};

Base foo_copy()
{
  std::cout << "foo_copy" << std::endl;
  Derived derived{true};
  return derived;
}

Base foo_move()
{
  std::cout << "foo_move" << std::endl;
  Derived derived{true};
  return std::move(derived);
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  (void)foo_copy();
  std::cout << std::endl;
  (void)foo_move();
}
```

Its output:

```
foo_copy
Base copy
Derived destruction
Flag: true
Base destruction
Base destruction

foo_move
Base move
Derived destruction
Flag: false
Base destruction
Base destruction
```

Comment: Moving from an object is supposed to leave it in a "valid but unspecified state". That means the usual operations such as destruction are supposed to work. If they don't you should probably delete the move constructor to avoid moves all together.

Comment: If the move really causes you a problem you should rethink the design.  `Derived` really shouldn't care if it's base object is move out from it.

Comment: @nwp `Base` subobject of the `Derived` object is leaved in "valid but unspecified state" after the move. But the state of the `Derived` object may base on the state of its `Base` subobject. And if the last changes without the corresponding changes in the first the code may behave differently or even incorrectly.

Comment: I would posit that it is not possible to write "good" code that displays the issue you are getting at. Relying on copy/move constructor side effects itself is already fragile as hell (due to the various elisions that are allowed to alter observable behavior). And if you don't rely on side effects per-se but moving out the base class breaks your class invariant, you shouldn't allow moving the base class.

Answer (score 7):

Clang's warning certainly is correct. Since `derived` is of a type that differs from the function's return type, in the statement `return derived;`, the compiler must treat `derived` as an lvalue, and a copy will occur. And this copy could be avoided by writing `return std::move(derived);`, making it into an rvalue explicitly. The warning doesn't tell you whether or not you **should** do this. It just tells you the consequences of what you're doing, and the consequences of using `std::move`, and lets you make up your own mind.

Your concern is that the destructor of `Derived` might access the `Base` state after it has been moved from, which might cause bugs. If such bugs do occur, it is because the author of `Derived` has made a mistake, not because the user should not have moved the `Base` subobject. Such bugs could be discovered in the same ways as other bugs, and reported to the author of `Derived`.

Why do I say this? Because when the author made `Base` a **public** base class of `Derived`, they were promising to the user that they are entitled to use the full `Base` interface whenever interacting with a `Derived` object, which includes moving from it. Thus, all member functions of `Derived` must be prepared to deal with the fact that the user may have modified the `Base` subobject in any way that `Base`'s interface allows. If this is not desired, then `Base` could be made a private base class of `Derived`, or a private data member, rather than a public base class.

Answer (score 5):

> Is -Wreturn-std-move clang warning correct in case of objects in the same hierarchy?

Yes, the warning is correct. The current rules for automatic move only happen if overload resolution finds a constructor that takes, *specifically*, and rvalue reference to that type. In this snippet:

> ```
> Base foo()
> {
>   Derived derived;
>   return derived;
> }
> ```

`derived` is an automatic storage object that is being returned - it's dying anyway, so it's *safe* to move from. So we try to do that - we treat it as an rvalue, and we find `Base(Base&&)`. That's a viable constructor, but it takes a `Base&&` - and we need *very specifically* a `Derived&&`. So end up copying.

But the copy is wasteful. Why copy when `derived` is going out of scope anyway? Why use the expensive operation when you can use the cheap one? That's why the warning is there, to remind you to write:

```
Base foo()
{
  Derived derived;
  return std::move(derived); // ok, no warning
}
```

Now, if slicing is wrong for this hierarchy, then even copying is doing the wrong thing anyway and you have other problems. But if slicing is acceptable, then you want to move here, not copy, and the language at the moment arguably does the wrong thing. The warning is there to help make sure you do the right thing.

---

In C++20, the original example would actually perform an implicit move due to [P1825](https://wg21.link/p1825) (the relevant part comes from [P1155](https://wg21.link/p1155)).

Comment: All you wrote is fine and correct but the problem in the destruction of the `Derived` object with the `Base` subobject leaved in some valid but unspecified state after the move. The logic of the `Derived` destruction may base on the `Base` internal state and if it is changed but `Derived` members are not changed correspondingly strange situation may occur.

Comment: @Constructor Then either (a) your move constructor shouldn't move, (b) you should disallow slicing as it may be inherently questionable (maybe `Base` shouldn't be a public `Base`?), or (c) both.

Comment: @Constructor Can you provide a non-contrived example of this? I worded my answer less stringently regarding slicing because _technically_ you could come up with such an example, but Barry kind of nails it here - your class either has problems with being sliced or it doesn't.

Comment: As I understand from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return#Notes), the slicing case would work as expected in C++20.

Answer (score 2):

It is commonly advised that the only classes in your hierarchy that are not abstract should be the leaf classes. Everything that is used as *polymorphic* base class should be abstract.

- [why derive from a concrete class is a poor design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724946/why-derive-from-a-concrete-class-is-a-poor-design)
- http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/020163371x/items/item33.html

This would make the original code (which clang warns about) illegal in the first place, as you would be unable to return a `Base` by value. And indeed, the original code leaves many questions open to a reader, primarily because it violates this guideline:

- What is the point of creating a `Derived` and only returning a `Base` by value?
- Is there any [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) happening here? Will it maybe happen in the future if someone adds code to either class?
- Relatedly, how do you want to enforce your class invariants if your classes are not polymorphic (no virtual destructors, to name one issue)?
- To satisfy the Liskov Substitution Principle, either all kinds of derived classes should allow having their `Base` subobjects moved out, or none of them. In the latter case, this can be prevented by deleting `Base`'s move constructor. In the former case, there is no issue with the warning.
- How convoluted would your class invariants have to be so that destroying a `Base` by itself is fine, destroying a `Derived` with its `Base` present is fine, but destroying a `Derived` without its `Base` would not be fine? Note that this is pretty much impossible if you follow the [rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

So yes, it is possible to write code where using `std::move` as clang suggests changes the meaning. But that code would have to violate a lot of coding principles already. I don't think it is reasonable to expect the compiler *warnings* to respect that possibility.

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning that the warning doesn't trigger if Base has its move constructor deleted, which it should be if moving from Base can violate its invariants or its derived classes' invariants.

Comment: "*Everything that is used as base class should be abstract.*" This is only good advice if you're using inheritance for polymorphic reasons. In C++, inheritance has other uses.

Comment: @NicolBolas True, but how many of those uses involve convoluted class invariants that would be fine with sliced `Base` copies but not a `Base`-moved-from `Derived`? Or rather, how many of those even have non-defaulted destructors? Anyway, I have amended my answer, thank you!